# Xcode 13 SwiftUI Preview does not support Text operator +

Tags: swiftui, preview, xcode13

Seems Xcode 13 SwiftUI does not support + operator. For example

```
Text("Not you? Hit the")
                        + Text(" ‘Back’ ").fontWeight(.bold)
                        + Text("arrow and use a different email.")
```

Because of an error of

```
ambiguous operator declarations found for operator

----------------------------------------

CompileDylibError: Failed to build WarningRedirectToLoginView.swift

Compiling failed: ambiguous operator declarations found for operator

/Users/liang.wang.cm/Documents/Project/Demo-IOS/Demo/View/Login/WarningRedirectToLoginView.swift:23:192: error: ambiguous operator declarations found for operator
                    Text(__designTimeString("#6206.[1].[2].property.[0].[0].arg[0].value.[0].arg[2].value.[1].arg[0].value.[0].[0]", fallback: "Looks like you already have an account for ")) +
                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
Swift.:1:16: note: found this matching operator declaration
infix operator + : AdditionPrecedence
               ^
Demo_Dev.:1:16: note: found this matching operator declaration
infix operator + : DefaultPrecedence
               ^
```

Comment: Can't duplicate the issue. Xcode 13.3.1. Are you sure there is not some hidden character in between?

Answer (score 0):

you **can** add `Text` together in SwiftUI. Here is an example that works for me: make sure the spacing is correct, (blank space (or more) before `+` blank space (or more) after).
You can also use a HStack

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Not you? Hit the") + Text(" ‘Back’ ").fontWeight(.bold) + Text("arrow and use a different email.")
        
        HStack {
            Text("text1").foregroundColor(.green)
            Text(" text2 ").foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("text3").foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Note the error seems to indicate that you have declared a `+` operator for your own purpose. The compiler may be confused about that.